# Why does my observe added get called every time

Tags: meteor

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   Posts.find().observe({
      added: function (doc) {
         // why does this get called on startup for every document?
      }
   });
});
```

**What am i trying to do**

Listen for new added posts and update another collection.

**But why**

does my oberve.added code run every time i start my meteor application? I just need it to run when there is is a new post added

*Thank you*

Comment: I actually tried that. still gets called every time on startup. for every document. weird i don't understand it. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, try using `observeChanges` in your `Posts` subscription `onReady` callback.

Comment: i need to run this on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There's kind of an example in the docs on how to accomplish this. It is written under [Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish). The idea is the following:

```js
  var initializing = true;

  // observeChanges only returns after the initial `added` callbacks
  // have run.
  var handle = <Collection>.find(<selector>).observeChanges({
    added: function (id) {
      if(!initializing){
         // A new was added!
      }
    }
  });

  initializing = false;
```